# echoing the text message from textarea via PHP and AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, textarea

HTML:

```
   <div class="mb-3">
       <label for="comment" class="form-label">Comments</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
```

javascript:

```
let comment = $('textarea.msg').val()
alert(comment);
```

and then PHP:

```
echo $_POST['comment'];
echo isset($_POST['comment']);
echo trim($_POST['comment']) != '';
```

Here, the Response tab in Network tab of Firefox Inspect shows nothing for the echo commands in PHP. I am not sure why the textarea input `hi` is not shown hence not inserted.

Even for the javascript alert of comment variable, I get this:

[image]

Comment: There is no `msg` class in this HTML. Unclear how `alert(comment);` relates to the PHP.

Comment: Whenever you chain things and get null, undefined, etc.  unwind the chain.

Comment: @user3783243 I found it in this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467223/2414957 so how do I access the message?

Comment: The easiest is to use the ID

Comment: You shouldn't just copy things, understand what they are doing. `$_POST['comment']` should be correct if you are submitting the form via HTML submit. The JS doesn't make sense though unless you are submitting the data via AJAX, if that is the case then the value is never set. `textarea.msg` is saying to look for a `textarea` element with a class (because of the `.`) of `msg`. So `$('#comment')` might be what you want, this also presumes there is only one comment on the page, if not than you need to make the `id` unique.

Comment: @ChrisHaas  let comment = $('#comment').val().trim();
    alert(comment); --> made it visible by alert (I saw hi) however, still don't see the value of echo $_POST['comment']; in PHP Response.

Comment: Need to see how JS `comment` maps to PHP. That is missing from this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let comment = $('#comment').val().trim();
```

Credits to Chris Haas.

Comment: Or no jQuery, `document.getElementById("comment").value` or `document.querySelector("#comment").value`. Really no major reason to trim, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="comment" class="form-label">Comments</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

id is unique in the HTML and with jquery it would be easier to target the element you want. For class we use `$(.<classNAME>)` while for id we use `$(#<id_Name>)`

Your Case, `$('#comment').val()`